# which technique can I use to load an object's value in a form field and then update that value making it available to my $scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an app that you can create, update and delete notes. I am wondering which technique I could use to load the value I want in the form field and still make it available to my `$scope` variable in the controller. It seems like I can't have both things going on (either start the form empty and then use `ng-model="title"` i.e. or I could load the value using `value="{{note.title}}"`, but then I can't make the value from the field available in the controller to then update my note.

I believe it's very simple solution but I just could not find the answer in other sources.

**index.html**

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" controller="notesCtrl" id="/notes.html">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9" style="position: relative">
        <form ng-submit="updateNote()" >
          <div class="row">.</div>
          <div class="row">
            <input type="text"   class="form-control" value="{{note.title}}" >
            <div class="row">.</div>
            <input type="text" class ="form-control" value="{{note.body}}"    style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
            <div class="row">.</div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Save Note</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and my controller in **app.js**

```
   .controller('notesCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    'notesFactory', 
    'note', 
    '$stateParams', function(
        $scope, 
        notesFactory, 
        note, 
        $stateParams) {
        $scope.note = note;

        $scope.updateNote = function() {
        notesFactory.update(
            $stateParams.id,
            {
                title: $scope.title,
                body: $scope.body
            })
        }
 }])
```

Comment: what you're describing is 2-way data binding and is the basis for how angular works, the key is not to use form fields `value` attribute but `ng-model `instead. check the tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: thanks @ketan. You're right and the answer below follows  what you stated  . That way I fixed it. I was already using that as default for two way data binding. I just was wandering around trying to find a way to make that data available in the form and still be able to update it. Got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="title">
```

Script:

```
.controller('notesCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    'notesFactory', 
    'note', 
    '$stateParams', function(
        $scope, 
        notesFactory, 
        note, 
        $stateParams) {
        $scope.note = note;

        $scope.title = 'titleValue' //YOUR VALUE GOES HERE

        $scope.updateNote = function() {
        notesFactory.update(
            $stateParams.id,
            {
                title: $scope.title,
                body: $scope.body
            })
        }
 }])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @pratik. I'm quite new to angularjs as well as programming in general . I didn't think of setting the value of the scope before the updateNote function. It worked and solved the problem.

Comment: No probs, understand the concept of $scope very well, it will help to understand other fundamentals in future, good luck @vinibol12